# php pdo don't save on table innodb

Tags: php, mysql

please some can help me ?

i try to convert the hold php in pdo code but
in general the codes does not work pdo if i use Innodb table
esemple...
this code save on table Myisam but not save if i trasform table in Innodb why ?

```
try{
// lancio di una transazione con PDO
$pdo->beginTransaction();

//Preparazione query
$q = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tipomiele (nometipomiele, notetipomiele) VALUES (:nometipomiele, :notetipomiele)");

//binding
$q->bindParam(':nometipomiele', $nometipomiele);
$q->bindParam(':notetipomiele', $notetipomiele);//ricorda di "collegare" la giusta variabile al bind

//esecuzione
$q->execute(); // eseguo la query


 }
 // se qualcosa non è andato a buon fine


 // blocco catch per la gestione delle eccezioni
catch(pdoException $e) {
///personalizzazione pagine di rientro
 echo 'Attenzione: '.$e->getMessage();

  // notifica in caso di errore
  $output = "Impossibile collegarsi al Data Base, Utente o Password errati" . "<br>" . "<br>" . "prego riprovare" . $e .
              "<br>" . "<br>" . "<a href='miele.php'>Clicca QUI per ritornare alla pagina principale</a>";
    include 'errore.html.php';
        // ritorno alla situazione precedente
        $pdo->rollBack();
        exit ();
}
// ritorno alla situazione precedente
$pdo->rollBack();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: I thing it rollbacks what you have saved. Try after commenting `$pdo->rollback()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are rolling back your changes every time by calling `$pdo->rollBack();` at the end of your script. You should only call `$pdo->rollBack();` in your `catch` block and remove the `$pdo->rollBack();` and the end of your script.

Your code is working with `MyISAM` tables because the `MyISAM` engine does not support transactions so that `$pdo->rollBack();` has no effect.